# Sublime 3 Win 7 x64 SideBarEnhancements plugin not working properly

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Wondering if anyone can duplicate this issue or if I'm just missing something here:

Win 7 x64

Install [Sublime 3 Win x64](http://www.sublimetext.com/3)

Install [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation)

Restart Sublime

Install [SideBarEnhancements](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements) using Package Control

Restart Sublime

Show the sidebar, right click on a file, I only see the Close option, none of the fancy new stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read through the full README to the [FAQ](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements#faq), you'll find the following:

> Q: Why the menu is not shown on Open Files?
>
> - It should be mentioned that the package's context menu is only available for files and folders **in a project (section `Folders` in the side bar)**, and not on the open files listed at the top of the side bar, due to a limitation of ST.

So, it's not a bug, just a limitation of the underlying program. Expanding the sidebar API has been requested of the author in a number of forums, we'll just have to wait and see if it happens.